# Keep <C-X> <C-F> filename completion menu alive between directories

Tags: autocompletion, ins-completion

I'd like to use `<C-X> <C-F>` to autocomplete a long filename in insert mode, say `/foo/bar/baz.txt`. When I type in `/f`, I can press `<C-X> <C-F>` to complete to `/foo/`. However, after typing `/foo/b`, I'll need to press `<C-X> <C-F>` again to complete to `/foo/bar/`. After typing `/foo/bar/b`, I'll need to press `<C-X> <C-F>` one more time to get to `/foo/bar/baz.txt`. Is there any way to keep the completion menu alive inbetween directory slashes `/` for longer filenames?

Comment: Welcome to [vi.se]!

Comment: Thanks! I'm surprised I haven't gotten an answer yet, and I can't find anything off of Google or :help. Do people use <C-X> <C-F> regularly? Or is this functionality usually handled by a plugin?

Comment: @identicon patience is a virtue... the question has only been around for 15 hours. I use `<C-X><C-F>` regularly, but I've never minded typing it each time.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

(Untested) You'll need a vim that supports `CompleteDonePre`. You can check with

```
echo has('##CompleteDonePre') ? 'supported' : 'not supported'
```

If you have this event, you can use the following autocommand:

```
augroup ContinueFileCompletion
  autocmd!
  autocmd CompleteDonePre * if complete_info()['mode'] ==# 'files' | call feedkeys("\<C-x>\<C-f>", 'n') | endif
augroup END
```

Notes

1. You might be able to get away with `normal! <C-x><C-f>` instead of `call feedkeys(...)`; I'm not sure in this case, since we're doing this from an autocommand
2. You could modify this to also check if the completed item was a directory. I would probably extract a function at this point and call it in the autocommand, but the check could be something like

```
let compinfo = complete_info()
let compitem = compinfo['items'][compinfo['selected']]
" use compitem, which is a dictionary... (:help complete-items)
```

3. This doesn't handle aborted completions; you can check if the dictionary `v:completed_item` is empty for that (I think—the help says "if completion failed", and the event is triggered when "something was completed or abandoning completion"). `empty(v:completed_item)` would do the trick.

Comment: Hm. Since this doesn't check for failed completion, it's *very* possible you'll get stuck in a loop with this.

Comment: This looks like it works, but I don't seem to have a Vim supporting `CompleteDonePre`... Regardless, thanks for coming up with a way to do this! I'll give you the selected answer.

As for a plugin approach, YouCompleteMe (in @Dmitry's answer) works, as well as [fzf](https://github.com/junegunn/fzf.vim).

Answer (score 0):

[YouCompleteMe](https://github.com/ycm-core/YouCompleteMe) plugin does the thing. But it may be overwhelming if you need only file path autocompletion. YCM is not so easy to use, it is python dependant, requires compilation, much space on disk and works with certain file types. To enable it on any file type you have to specify one of acceptable. For example:

```
:set filetype=python
```

Then you just type path in text and it completes on each slash. As bonus you will get fuzzy search.